# How to encourage new raspberry stalks to grow away from the main stalk?

Tags: mulch, raspberries, air-flow

Here's a photo of my Canby raspberry plant. The new stalks are only growing near the original stalk. My Fall Gold raspberry plant is also doing the same thing. Is this caused by my mulching? I would actually prefer the new stalks to grow away from the main stalk so that there's better airflow. A row of plants would be more aesthetically appealing also.

[image]

As a side question: are red raspberry's supposed to be yellow before they're ripe? My Fall Gold (yellow) is nearby and maybe the cross pollination caused my Canby to become yellow too. Can cross pollination even do that?

Answer (score 3):

It's because raspberry plants grow from a crown, which stays small, and the stems grow up and out from that point. It's entirely healthy. The new canes will emerge near where the old ones did, but they will arch away or can be trained outward. For a row of plants, you will need to either buy new plants, or with some varieties, such as regular raspberries (yours are primocanes) the stem tips will layer in the soil, forming new plants which can be moved.

Raspberries do not sucker, but blackberries can. They'll sometimes send out underground stems and come up in new places. Given time, these new plants can be detached and moved.

On the yellow coloring, red raspberries don't usually become that yellow while ripening; I think your plant was mislabeled. They will probably stay yellow. Canby and fall Gold are both primocane raspberries, but cross-pollination doesn't cause a change in fruit color.

Comment: I've seen a Youtube video of a guy bending over a blackberry stalk into the soil to propagate it far away from its origin. Can the same thing be done to raspberries?

Comment: See my answer - '*the stem tips will layer in the soil, forming new plants which can be moved.*' So yes, but with primocanes, you have to do it yourself, before the flowerhead forms.

Comment: @JMusser - I'd argue with your statement 'raspberries don't sucker'. In my experience, they march, so to speak, and appear further away, so that your original raspberry bed, 4 years later, has moved itself 3 feet away (in my case, into the shrubs planted nearby)

Comment: @Bamboo mostly by stem tip layering unless you have a different kind of raspberry over there :P.

Comment: Here's a [close up photo of the berries](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BwdR1o8CEAI4irx.jpg:large). Notice how one of them is so ripe that it's falling off by itself? If they fully ripen with a gold color, then I guess they won't ever become red. I was jipped, I tells yah! Can't believe I got 2 Fall Golds. I prefer a Garden of Eden - one fruit tree of every variety.

Comment: @JoJo Like I thought. you plant was mislabeled or something. If you have the receipt, you could probably get your money back. I noticed you have 'one of everything'. It's really cool.